# jquery autocomplete doesn't get response in firefox

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

When I put autocomplete.ashx file under staging server and test from my local, the autocomplete function works only at IE. No response in firefox (Checked in firebug).
But it works both IE and FireFox in my local iis . Any advise?

### My jquery

```
$("#txtautocomplete").autocomplete("http://mystagingserver.com/myautocomplete/autocomplete.ashx?q=Contains,111,10",
                 {                
                delay:400,
                minChars:3,               
                matchSubset:1,
                matchContains:1,
                cacheLength:10,
                selectFirst: false,
                selectOnly: false,
                scroll:true,
                autoFill:false
                });
```

### ASHX code

Check paramater
return string in line (e.g "apple" "orange" "mango")

### From page

include

Comment: what happens when you acceess the url directly???

Comment: If i access directly with Firebox, get the response string correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like SOP(same origin policy). You are not allowed to make cross domain ajax calls unless you use JsonP. Does it work if you run the JQuery on the stagingserver?

Comment: @cool rock might be , access the url directly and if it gets the results that means its same as mikale said.

Comment: it works at staging server. Thanks for your reply. I will look around to use JsonP for that ajax call.